Formalizing the intuition of thinking of balls in a metric space as intervals in the positive real line
Suppose we pick a point in a metric space, then we can order the rest of the points in a metric space relative to it(*). This idea is captured through the idea of balls centered around that point. Interestingly the theorems that we would think are true by interpretting that point as a point on the line, and ball as an open interval centered around that point, are actually true. For example, consider a point $m$ in a metric space $(M,d)$ and let $a,b,c$ be elements in the image of $d$ (possible elements in the image) then we have  if $a<b<c$ then $B_a (m) \subset B_b (m) \subset B_c (m) $ *
Another example we consider a ball $B_r(m)$ then consider some other element $m'$ in it, we can say prove that the maximum size of ball around $m'$ such that it is still a subset is $B_{r-d(m',r)} (m)$. But, similarly if we have the set $a-\epsilon<a<a+\epsilon$  and a point in $b$ inside then the maximum size interval in that about $b$ is, $b- (\epsilon-d(a,b) )<b< b+ (\epsilon-d(a,b) )$ where $d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R }$
Similarly we can also find analogies between results of intersections and unions. Of course, $R$ it self is a metric space with the usual metric, but is there any another way to justify why the reasoning about metric balls in $R$ extrapolates so well into general metric space? I think it maybe also have to do with the fact that the image of the metric function is subset of $\mathbb{R}$ too.
I think maybe there is some functional/categorical connection going on here, but I don't have enough knowledge to precisely formulate it.

*: Suppose we choose a point $x$ in the metric space, then we can define an order relation on the set; $a<b$   if $d(x,a) < d(x,b)$.

Note, if $a<b,$ it is possible $B_a(m)=B_b(m),$ in general. There are certainly some properties of intervals that generalize, but that's because open (bounded) intervals of the real line are open balls in a metric space.

An example, if $M=(\mathbb R\times{0})\cup {(0,1)}$ inheriting the usual metric from $\mathbb R^2.$ Then the image of the metric is all of the non-negative reals, but $m=(0,1)$ has $B_r(m)={m}$ for all $0<r<1.$

I think the intention was "the image of $d(m, -)$".

Again it is not true that the maximum ball around $m'$ contained in $B_r(m)$ is known. The simplest example is when $B_r(m)$ is all of $M,$ but there are other examples. For example, if $M={(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1 \lor y=-1},$ then $m'=(0,1/2)\in B_1((0,0)),$ but $B_{3/2}(m')\subseteq B_1((0,0)).$

For the first thing, maybe the fact you're looking for is that the assignment of balls $B_{-}(m)$ is a functor from $(\mathbb{R}_+, \leq)$ to $(\mathcal{P}(M), \subseteq)$?

Your opening sentence is entirely unclear to me. What does it mean to you "to order the points in the metric space"? At first reading I thought it meant "to put an order relation on the set of points in the metric space"... but that makes no sense... and I cannot imagine what else you mean instead.

Or even simpler, if $M=[-1,1)$ in the real line, then if $m'\in B_1(0),$ and $m'>0,$ then the radius for $m'$ is $1+m'.$

The only other thing I can imagine is that you are using the function $x \mapsto d(m,x)$ to put a partial order on the set of points in the metric space, where $x < y$ if and only if $d(m,x)<d(m,y)$. In that case, there is certainly a theorem which says that for any set $X$, any (partially) ordered set $A$, and any function $f : X \to A$, one obtains a partial order on the set $X$ by the formula $x < y \iff f(x) < f(y)$. The partial order obtained will generally violate the trichotomy law $x<y$ OR $x=y$ OR $x>y$.

Yes, that is exactly what I meant @LeeMosher

Please give example of the trichotomy violation @LeeMosher

In the metric space $\mathbb R$, with $m=0$, the points $x=-1$ and $y=+1$ violate the trichotomy law.

@NaïmFavier Yes, I think that is around what I need. Do you have a reference?

In general, in any metric space $M$, for any $m \in M$ and any $r>0$, if there are two distinct points on the "sphere of radius $r$ around $m$" then those two points violate the trichotomy law.

Ah okay, that makes sense.. but it is not a big problem. I think intuitively speaking, thinking of metric spaces through this definition is reductive as we can no longer talk about "directions"

Metric spaces are indeed closely related to $\mathbb{R}$. For starters by definition (metric function takes values in $\mathbb{R}$). But there is more, in fact every metric space arises as a subset of some normed real vector space (up to isometry). And so, yes, it is not a coincidence that they share some properties. But on the other hand these are not close enough to think about balls as intervals.

It would be better to think of balls in metric spaces as being like disks in the plane instead of intervals on the line. Intervals have several properties not shared by most balls, including being ordered vs. the partial order that you defined, as Lee Mosher has already discussed ("order" by itself means "total order", not partial order). Another is that removing a single point disconnects an interval, but in general not a ball. It is true that disks in the plane also have properties not shared by all balls, but they are less likely to be misleading than intervals.
